# The sum of prime numbers

Tags: c

I want to calculate the sum of even prime numbers between 101 and 203. But the output for my code is wrong, the output is 52.
Can anyone help me please to get the correct output, in my code I supposed that the even numbers are sure not prime that's why I escaped them. I want to solve it using this method by the prime function. What should I do? Thank you a lot

```
#include <stdio.h>
int prime(int n)
{
    int i=2;
    int n2;
    n2 = n/2;
    while (1<=n2) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=101; i<=203; i+=2) {
        if (prime(i)==1) {
        }
        sum+=1;
    }
    printf("%d \n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **even prime numbers between 101 and 203**???

Comment: did you intend to count or get the sum?

Comment: `sum += i` if `i` is prime...

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.

In the `for` loop:

```
    for (int i=101; i<=203; i+=2) {
    if (prime(i)==1){
    }sum+=1;
```

The statement `sum+=1` should be inside the `if` block.

Also, you are adding `1` to `sum`. Instead, you should add `i` as you want the sum of prime numbers as result:

```
sum+=i;
```

The function `prime()` should return `1` only when `while` loop checks condition `n%i == 0` for all the values of `i` and for none of the value of `i` it is `true`. So, you need to move `return 1` to out of the `while` loop.

Also, in the `while` loop in `prime()` this is incorrect:

```
while (1<=n2) {
```

It should be:

```
while (i<=n2) {
```

Collectively, it should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int prime(int n)
{
    int i=2;
    int n2;
    n2 = n/2;
    while (i<=n2) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
   }
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=101; i<=203; i+=2) {
        if (prime(i)==1){
            sum+=i;
        }
    }

    printf("%d \n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you do not need 'i++;' in your prime-method because this is unreachable code.

Second: try this function for checking if a number is prime:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int prime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0 && i != n) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=101; i<=203; i+=2) {
        if (prime(i)==1){
          sum+=i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d \n",sum);
}
```

Comment: So I think the result should be 3167

Answer (score 0):

THERE ARE NO SUCH THING AS EVEN PRIME NUMBERS... YOU WILL ALWAYS GET 0.

But to really answer your question...

You really don't need to put i++ in your first function. Secondly, try this

```
for (int i=101; i<=203; i++)
{
   i++
   if (prime(i)==1)
   {
     sum+=i;
   }
}
```

This should work. You don't need to increment sum by 1, you need to add i each time there is a prime number. The reason why you get 52 is because you do sum+=1, which adds 1 to sum 52 times in the for loop.

Comment: There is such a thing as even prime numbers.

Comment: The is one possible even number, two. As far as I am aware, two does not fall in the range they are looking for.

Comment: So say that in the answer.